# MySQL : Insert into... Select from .... On Duplicate Key

Tags: mysql

I have a record from **table A** say :

```
_____________________________________________________________________________
    Date       |      country        |      channel      |       clicks  
_____________________________________________________________________________
    1-01-2016  |         US          |        MTV        |        100

    1-01-2016  |         US          |        MTV        |         50
_____________________________________________________________________________
```

I insert this record into another **table B** Using the query :

```
INSERT INTO B 
SELECT 
  DATE,
  country,
  channel,
  SUM(clicks) AS clicks 
FROM
  A 
GROUP BY DATE,
  country,
  channel;
```

Now **Table B** looks like :

```
_____________________________________________________________________________
    Date       |      country        |      channel      |       clicks  
_____________________________________________________________________________
    1-01-2016  |         US          |        MTV        |        150
_____________________________________________________________________________
```

At some other instant in time I get another record in **table A** say

```
_____________________________________________________________________________
        Date       |      country        |      channel      |       clicks  
_____________________________________________________________________________
        1-01-2016  |         US          |        MTV        |        300
_____________________________________________________________________________
```

Now I want to **update** the old record in **table B** which should look like this :

```
_____________________________________________________________________________
        Date       |      country        |      channel      |       clicks  
_______________________________________________________________________________
        1-01-2016  |         US          |        MTV        |        450
_____________________________________________________________________________
```

How can I do this with **MySQL**

Comment: @e4c5 Wrong link?

Comment: @jens, the op has asked a lot of questions with no further action

Comment: @e4c5 But your link answers the question, what is to do after some one answered?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same query (used to `insert`) along with `INNER JOIN` in order to update.

```
UPDATE B
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    DATE,
    country,
    channel,
    SUM(clicks) AS clicks 
  FROM  A 
  GROUP BY DATE,  country,   channel
)AS t
ON B.Date = t.Date AND B.country = t.country AND B.channel = t.channel
SET B.clicks = t.clicks;
```

**EDIT:**

In order to `update/insert` through the same query.

```
INSERT INTO B SELECT
    t.DATE,
    t.country,
    t.channel,
    t.clicks
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        DATE,
        country,
        channel,
        SUM(clicks) AS clicks
    FROM A
    GROUP BY DATE, country, channel 
) AS t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clicks = t.clicks
```

Comment: Can you edit it and make it an insert statement instead that updates if the record exists. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to update or insert through the same query? If so, then do you have any unique key in your table?

Comment: Yes the primary key is (Date,country,channel)

Comment: There's an issue in the previous edit. Please check the query under edit section.

Comment: OK sir, let me check. Thanks

Comment: It's not adding the new and old values , instead it assigns the new value '300' to clicks while the expected value is 450

Comment: Have you run the above query after the new value being inserted into `A` table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123770/discussion-between-danish-bin-sofwan-and-1000111).